# Getting Paged Results with Datastax Java Cassandra driver version 4.15.0

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Hello I am confused on using querying through Datastax Java driver and not being able to get past the limit of only 2,100 results returned. In the documentation and countless references online I see the following code example

```
for (Row row : rs) {
    if (rs.getAvailableWithoutFetching() == 100 && !rs.isFullyFetched())
        rs.fetchMoreResults(); // this is asynchronous
    // Process the row ...
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

where rs.fetchMoreResults() is available as a method on the ResultSet, in version 4.15.0 , i can see getAvailableWithoutFetching() and is rs.fullyFetched() which seems to always return true despite my query expecting to return many thousands of results and there is **no fethMoreResults() method available on this driver version**, every time I can only get 2,100 results. This is my code

```
SimpleStatement st = new SimpleStatementBuilder("SELECT * FROM " + StreamDataTables.VAR_SNAPSHOT).build();
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(st); //CqlSession being used
        Iterator<Row> iterator = rs.iterator();
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            rowCount++;
            System.out.println("fully fetched " + rs.isFullyFetched());
            
        }
        System.out.println("Results returned : " + rowCount);
```

Every time the row count is 2,701 despite more records in the table,  and the only way i could try to get that is to cast the ResultSet to a DefaultAsyncResultSet which is the instance returned and the class has methods like hasNextPage() etc. which is what I am expecting, but throws a class cast exception saying something like app module not loaded.

So how in the world do I figure out how to get all the results which is way more than 2,100 returned in my query! **its driving me nuts.**